# Setting DataBodyRange2 = DataBodyRange1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write some code that stores a table of data in another tab, but that data is a bit large and for some reason copy-pasting the values into the second table runs very slow (despite doing it quickly in another book but, not in a table). I'm trying to find a quicker way to do it, so my first thought was to try and assign the second table's DataBodyRange to the first's but I'm having some issues with it. Below is essentially what I tried to run for this piece of the code, which gives no errors but also gives no results.

```
Dim previous_data As Range
Set previous_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
Dim new_data As Range
Set new_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange

previous_data = new_data
```

Do I need an extra/different step to actually add the data into the worksheet or is there a better way to go about this that runs efficiently?

Comment: Hmm. Really you should be explicit that you are assigning the `.Value` of one range to the `.Value` of another. Are the tables the exact same size (number of rows and columns)? If not, you could probably use `Resize` here.

Comment: That smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You usually don't want to duplicate data in a workbook. Could you share what you're planning to do with the copy or with the original? Also, sharing the code for *despite doing it quickly in another book but, not in a table* might be useful. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68279306/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.Value` property for both sides of the expression. Works without `.Resize` for different table sizes.

```vb
Sub test1()
    Dim previous_data As Range, new_data As Range
    Set previous_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    Set new_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange
    
    previous_data.Value = new_data.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to copy the new data below the previous data? As you have mentioned "Previous data is a bit large", it seems you are accumulating data on Sheets(1). Then you will have to offset the previous date to copy the new data below it.

```
Sub test()
Dim previous_data As Range
Set previous_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
Dim new_data As Range
Set new_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange
Dim Target_Range As Range
Set Target_Range = previous_data.Offset(1).Resize(new_data.Rows.Count, new_data.Columns.Count)
Target_Range.Value = new_data.Value

End Sub
```